# How can I copy mp3 files from my asset folder to documentdirectory and then share it for example over whatsapp in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to programm a soundboard. My mp3 files are in the asset folder. But I dont know how to share these files in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...

With this Method I can copy my Assets

Future writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    return new File(path).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
  }